# Commenting out in HTML editor breaks template

Tags: code, html-editor

There is a certain section of HTML that I need to comment out within the HTML editor in Wordpress.  But when I do so, it breaks the HTML. After looking at the source code, I noticed that it converts the ending comment of this:

```
-->
```

To this:

```
&#8211;>
```

Anyone know how to go about commenting out HTML code within the editor without it converting it to that character?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I need to remove a div but it's going to be added back in later.  Meh...you know what, I'll just do it with CSS.

Comment: However, it would be nice to know (for the rest of the community) why it changes that and if there is any way around it...

Comment: Because TinyMCE only allows a subset of tags for security reasons. You shouldn't need to include div tags in content anyway, content is for content, layout belongs in the theme templates and stylesheets

Comment: Try looking into shortcodes of the form [shortcode]content here[/shortcode]

Comment: See my answer, I have a solution for you!

Answer (score 1):

My last comment reminded me about shortcodes, and lead me to this answer:

```
function htmlcomment_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<!-- ' . $content . ' -->';
}
add_shortcode( 'htmlcomment', 'htmlcomment_shortcode' );
```

Add that to `functions.php` or your plugin, and then use it in your content like this:

> normal text [htmlcomment]commented out text[/htmlcomment]